# Git merging using ours and theirs in custom way

Tags: git, merge

I want to merge branch release on branch master such that I resolve all conflicts in favor of master (ours) except for a particular folder for which I want resolve all in favor of release (theirs). Is there a clean way of doing this?

Basically I am trying to fix something messed up by earlier merges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say there are three folders `foo/`, `bar/` and `fizz/`, and you are in favor of `release` for `fizz` and `master` for the rest.

```
#you've encountered the conflicts during a merge
git checkout master -- . ':!fizz/'
git checkout release -- fizz/
git commit
```

`. ':!fizz/'` means all except `fizz/`. So `foo/` and `bar/` of `master` are checked out. Likewise, `fizz/` of `release` is checked out. In the end, `git commit` finishes the merge process.

Update:

As @torek 's comment says, the steps above works as `-s ours` for subfolders (note that there is NOT `-s theirs`). It ignores all the changes of "theirs". If what you want is to automatically pick our changes only for conflicting parts and just let it be if the merge is okay, then it should use something like `git merge -X ours` and `git merge -X theirs`, and don't run the commands in the answer. As @torek says, `git merge-file --ours/--theirs` work.

Comment: Note that this does not resolve *conflicts* in favor of ours/theirs, but rather resolve *entire files* in favor of ours/theirs. To resolve individual conflicts a la recursive merge's `-X` option, use `git merge-file` on each file, with `--ours` or `--theirs` as appropriate per file. This requires a bit of scripting, using, e.g., `git checkout-index --stage=all` to extract the conflicting index versions.

Comment: @torek thanks for your comment. I'll update the answer to make it clear.